# Converting "class" into "react hooks"

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to convert from "class component"  to "react hooks"

Here's the code for "class component": https://codesandbox.io/embed/p2lrxrx30
Which is working but when we click "submit button" an alert shows up.

here's the code that I'm trying to convert to "react hooks":
https://codesandbox.io/s/01r7m6k94w?fontsize=14

the problem is in this line:

```
form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
```

How could I fix it with using react-hooks?

Answer (score 3):

Your handleSubmit function no longer exists. change your code to:

```
    <form onSubmit={doSubmit}>
    ...
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a function that donot exist in the parent function, Please find the sandbox below, Please feel free to ask doubts if any

PS: Have also added onChange handles for text inputs using hooks

https://codesandbox.io/s/pwpvj0l8z7?fontsize=14

Comment: Thanks for providing an example!